# How to calculate height of html string?

Tags: html, objective-c, ios4, nsstring, css

I want to display html text on a label(TTStyleLabel). I am receieving text in form of html. How do I calculate height of html string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get height of html text you need to put that html info uiwebview. After loading the html in uiwebview you can get its height in its delegate methods like this -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webview.delegate = self;
    [webview loadHTMLString:@"<div id='foo' style='background: red'>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</div>" baseURL:nil];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *output = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"foo\").offsetHeight;"];
    NSLog(@"height: %@", output);
}
```

But if you are not displaying the text on the screen using the webview (as you are using a TTStyleLabel) you can hide the webview and load the html in it. You need to perform some tricks.

Comment: you mean to say first parse html in webView and then get height from webView and assign that height+ some margin to TTStyleLable?

Comment: sent you mail on your gmail address