# dynamic height for UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` inside my `UITableViewCell`. I have a `NSAttributeString` inside this displayed (I am using this [framework](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/uiwebview-must-die/). Basically what I want to do is to adjust the size of the cells and the UIScrollView as well.

If the text in the `NSAttributeString` can fit in a `UIScrollView` less than 500, then the `UIScrollView` gets that height. Otherwise let the `UIScrollView` height's be 500.

Now the problem is that it gets more complicated than that. The `NSAttributeString` is an HTML and so it's hard to estimate the height of the row just by treating the HTML as strings as it can have image etc. So is there a way to go around this, so I can set the height of each row dynamically according to the content of the `UIScrollView`...

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this kind of thing. Someone suggests me to get height using UIWebView when page loads get heigh by some javascript. Here is the original question

[How to calculate height of html string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247936/how-to-calculate-height-of-html-string)