# iOS - Resize UIWebView to fit content?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I need to be able to resize the height of a UIWebView until all the content is visible.

Is this possible?

Comment: @PengOne Just noting, this question applies to the iPad2 as well http://goo.gl/uvasi.

Comment: I am actually developing for ipad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247936/how-to-calculate-height-of-html-string maybe this helps

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After you have loaded content in the `UIWebView` you can use it's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method to ask the html document for its height. This is a little tricky but should work.

You can do something like this:

```
NSInteger height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.body.scrollHeight"] integerValue];
```

The scrollheight mught not be the best. You have a couple of options. Experiment with the document properties mentioned in http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/