# How to get height of HTML string that will be rendered?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I dynamically have html string to be rendered later on PDF. Before I render it to PDF, I want to calculate its height first, so I can move some of the HTML to next page.

Is it doable in Objective C? I don't want to load the HTML string first to web view to calculate the height as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247936/how-to-calculate-height-of-html-string), since memory consumption is very high for generating the dynamic HTML string.

Answer (score 3):

Load it into a `NSAttributedString` and then use `boundingRectWithSize` to get the size. (Note: that behind the scenes `NSAttributedString` passes the data to a web view to render the HTML)

```
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
CGRect rect = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
```